# Error/Empty in triggering form.$invalid

Tags: angularjs

```
<form class="form-inline" name="form" novalidate>
        <div class="sub-form" ng-form is-active ng-init="active = true" name="info">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-ie-4">
                <div class="select-input">
                  <label for="xyz">Xyz *</label>
                  <i class="fa fa-check-circle success" ng-show="form.info.xyz.$valid"></i>
                  <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
                  <i class="fa fa-times-circle error" ng-show="(form.info.xyz.$invalid && !form.info.xyz.$pristine)"></i>
                  <div class="styled-select">
                    <select
                      heights
                      name="xyz"
                      id="xyz"
                      ng-options="xyz.in as xyz.ft for xyz in xyzs"
                      ng-model="player.xyz"
                      required>
                      <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
             </div>
</form>

<div class="back-next-button-row">

    <div class="red-button tiny-button next-button" ng-if="form.$valid">
      <button ng-click="next()"><span class="button-text">Next</span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
    </div>

    <div class="red-button tiny-button next-button" ng-if="form.$invalid">
      <button ng-click="error()"><span class="button-text">Error</span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
    </div>

</div><!--back-next-button-row-->


In Script

 $scope.form = {};
    $scope.form.info = {};

    $scope.formError = function () {
      console.log($scope.form.info.xyz);
      //Getting Object {}

     }
```

While in html its showing proper objects that i expect
      Basically I would like to check 
       if($scope.form.info.xyz.$invalid){
       alert("Invlid")
       }

I would be thankful if I came to know why this is creating problem in this prospect

Answer (score 0):

With angular, you can do this inside the HTML and dont have to carry it to the script. If you want to check any form element is invalid or incomplete, you can add an element like this.

```
<p class="text-danger" ng-show="form.$invalid">Invalid</p>
```

If you still want to do on click, try the below.

In the HTML capture the form name on your function.

```
<button ng-click="next('form')">Validate</button>
```

In JS, you can have a function like the below,

```
$scope.next = function(form){
    if ($scope[form].$valid) {
        alert("True");
    } else {
        alert("Invalid");
    }    
};
```

Comment: Have to carry in controller due to some validtion on click

Comment: Ideal way is to enable the button when the form is valid, so you dont have to carry anything to the controller. These are the special stuffs we have to use rather going around. You can add ng-disable="form.$invalid", this will disable the button, so user cant click until its valid

Comment: But again still if I have to check console.log($scope[form].info.xyz.$invalid); It should return true if this is incorrect.

Comment: I appreciated your ans but I would like to check each field should validation if error function invoked

Comment: I am not following your last comment. DO you mean you want to check on each field and not just as a whole form ?

Comment: Yes correct want to check on each field and not just as a whole form ?

Comment: if xyz is valid than move to next lets say abc field

Comment: Even the current code will check each element and will alert. If you dont tell your requirement clear then cant help. You are expecting an alert at the end and the current code will behave the same. If one  or more of them is not valid, it will alert

Comment: Infact I did check that doesn't work for property $invalid its show blank object {}

Comment: does it causing i setup up $scope.form = {} empty object on intially

Comment: You mean you tried the updated answer which will validate onclick event? There I am only checking for $valid

Comment: yes that's correct. this is working fine for whole form but indivitual field doesn't work

Comment: When it works in whole it means its checking each and every element. What do you expect when you mean individual field. Do you expect the message referring to the field? because that was not your expectation initially

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but yes If individual field is invalid it should says this xyz field is invalid and stop execution. again if xyz valid move to next then check abc field and so on.

Comment: So its an additional requirement from where you started. Try to dump $scope[form] and check

Comment: Object { info: Object }
On info it is xyz : Object
and in it __proto__: Object
Nothing new

Expecting an object $valid : false

Comment: So you have the field name in that which you can use it. I believe 'xyz' is the field name.

Comment: Then you got what you need, alert that object and you are all set

Comment: I can achieve this by checking $scope.player.xyz == undefined it should alert("Invlid"); but don't knw is it proper way

Comment: Not following you and confused.. This may be the last one for me.. Are you expecting just Invalid as an alert or along with the field name. If field name, then you know how to get the variable name, I think you can get it from info. so go ahead